# ASP.NET MVC JSON over Fluent Nhibernate Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, castle, javascriptserializer

I am trying to return `JsonResult` using MVC controller standard `Json(object)` method. My object of type `Model1` is built by Fluent NHibernate.

`Model1` has property of type `Model2`. In debug mode I see that the environment creates a proxy descendant class of `Model2` called `Castle.Proxies.Model2Proxy`. This is used internally by Fluent Nhibernate, I believe, to satisfy my mappings. And in run time, actual model1.Model2 is of type `Castle.Proxies.Model2Proxy`.

The problem is that when my `Model1` is serialized, `Model2` is being serialized too. And the serializer seems to try to serialize all the properties of this object, including those generated by Castle and not needed by me. I would be OK with it if it did not cause an exception. Namely, somewhere inside this object a circular reference presents and the exception is caused by it. Here is the exception text:

`System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'`

I double checked my domain and found no circular references there, so I am blaming Castle. Am I correct? Is Castle really to blame for that? If so, what are my options? How do I tell serializer to ignore Castle properties? Particularly, how do I tell it to serialize the **defined** type, not the **actual** one?

I tend to covering my domain models with ViewModels to fight this issue, which is a recommended approach, but I would really love to know another cure, if it exists.

Comment: Does `Model2` have a reference to its parent, `Model1` by any chance?

Comment: No, it is definitely Castle proxy object which caused the exception: it contains `Type` object somewhere down the hierarchy, which has `RuntimeModule` reference. And the module, naturally, contains a reference to this `Type` in a collection of all types contained within this module.

Comment: Does this same error happen if you eagerly load Model2 and then serialize it?

Comment: @Cole W: I think it should not, as if I load it eagerly, it should become an entity of an expected type `Model2`, not he proxy. I will verify. I am not sure, however, that I want eager loading in my scenario.

Comment: @Michael, sJhonny answered what I was getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general, it's not good practice to serialize your model entities.
this is because you want to have complete control over what you serialize and send to the client.
when you serialize your model entities, you might be serializing the whole object graph associated with them, which you don't necessarily need / want.
(for example- if you want the user to view just a `Model1` entity, you might be sending along also a `Model2` entity, along with its `Model3` collection etc.)

the standard way to deal with it is using some sort of DTOs, which are adapted to display precisely what you want to display. for example:

```
public class Model1DTO
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
   public string Model2Name;
   //whatever other properties you need to display
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I came to (see _I tend to covering my domain models with ViewModels to fight this issue, which is a recommended approach_? You can call it DTO or whatever, still it is a cover). My question is more of a matter of interest for possible future implications and a note on how unpredictable such simple operations as "Jsoning" can be.

Comment: @Michael: sorry, I must have missed that sentence. Indeed it's the recommended approach, for the reasons I described above. As you say- "unpredictable" is precisely the right word. Since your Domain entities may have complex relationships with each other, some of them may be loaded to memory and some may not, you'd have much better control using 'flattened' objects such as DTOs or ViewModels.